# vmware vsphere clone vm

Tags: ip, virtual-machines, clone

this is my first time cloning a vm ubuntu 12.04 production server on a mvware esx enviroment. Thus I´m a bit scared of lose sight of something. The Server is nothing more than a webserver apache + postgresql Database, and uses openssh, Nagios for Monitoring and Amanda Backup by the way. Via Vmware Data client I´m not allowed to change something on the vswitch, means I´ve to give the Clone a new static Ip.

That´s what I did so far:

1. Make a Clone via Data Center
2. On Clone, deleted the Ethernet Card which was used for Amanda Backup
3. In Settings, switched of the Ethernet Card for Uplink (to avoid Ip conflicts between Server an its clone)
4. Checked Mac Adresses of NetworkCard (Vmaware changed them within the clone, great!)
5. Clone > Power On (with plugged of Network Cards)
6. Changed Static IP in /etc/network/interfaces
7. Changed hostname of clone

Not yet done (scared)

1. enable ethernet Card of cloned Server, means grant Server access to the web

Questions:

- Did I miss something? To change f.e. the Ip somewhere?
- What could happen in Worst Case? (The Live Server looses network connection because of an IP conflict?)

thanks for your help,

t book

Comment: Wait... ESX or ESXi?

Comment: its a esx server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have done things the right way :

- Checked for a new MAC address : OK
- Changed IP address : OK
- Changed hostname : OK

However double-check for the network interface number (`ethX`). I've noticed that sometimes cloned VMs change the `eth` number (`eth0` on the source becomes `eth1` on the clone)

Finally, make sure you have restarted the Network on the clone to make sure that your changes in `/etc/network/interfaces` are applied : `/etc/init.d/networking restart`

If you are not sure, restart the clone once again (still with Ethernet cards plugged off).

To be sure, on the clone, run a ping against the new ip address of the `ethX` interface and see if it is responding. If you have a reply it's OK.

Also (still from the clone and with network card still not connected) ping the actual live server ip. If you have no reply it is OK (that means you don't have a remaining reference somewhere to the old IP from the original live server).

Also, check your `/etc/hosts` file to make sure it has been updated with the new hostname.

Now, you can safely plug your clone Ethernet adapter.

And, as you said, the worst that could happen is an ip address conflict that could make your live server loose its network connectivity. But it should not happen if you have double-checked the above.

Comment: /etc/hosts was not updated, thanks again!